# jQuery pick second element on string

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.range-slider-price .range-info--label').attr('data-range-label', 'max').text()
```

My jQuery code return this string:

```
// return:
    "393,00 zł 2401,00 zł 49,90 zł 2499"
```

I need a pick a second element: `2401,00 zł`. Method .first() or .last() return only first or last element. Is it possible?

Comment: How about `String.split(' ')[INDEX_YOU_NEED]`

Comment: `$('.range-slider-price .range-info--label').attr('data-range-label', 'max')[1]`?  hard to tell since you did not post the html  SO we simply guess.

Comment: You shouldn't call `text()` on a bunch of elements if you only need one element's text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [`String.prototype.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) and RegEx `/([0-9]+,[0-9]+ zł)/g`.

Where:

`[0-9]+` ...`+` Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy).

`0-9`... Matches a single character in the range between 0 and 9.

`,`... Matches the character `,` literally (case sensitive)

`zł`... Matches the characters  `zł` literally (case sensitive).

**Demo:**

```js
var second = $('.range-slider-price .range-info--label').attr('data-range-label', 'max').text().match(/([0-9]+,[0-9]+ zł)/g)[1];
console.log(second);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="range-slider-price">
  <div class="range-info--label">393,00 zł 2401,00 zł 49,90 zł 2499</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the best solution but it works in your case

```
var text = "393,00 zł 2401,00 zł 49,90 zł 2499";
var textArray = text.split(' ')
var result = textArray[2] + " " +  textArray[3]
```